# What is meant by "paper outline (summary)"?

Tags: paper-submission

For a research competition, I am asked to upload a "paper outline (summary)". This seems a bit vague.

Does a paper outline usually mean a table-of-contents-esque section like [this](http://www.slide-talk.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Slide1-1-300x169.jpeg)? Or is it just asking for an abstract (this option makes less sense because I am asked to upload my full paper later on, which would include my abstract)?

This competition is based out of China if that information provides context that helps.

Comment: You might need to ask them. They might have a specific requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess (but can't know) that they are asking for an abstract. This is something useful to both an evaluator and to include in some publication.

An Table of Contents, on the other hand, is almost useless in knowing what is said in a paper: Introduction, Acknowledgements, Methodology, Main Results, Future Work, Conclusion. What have you learned about the paper from that ToC?

But, only the organizers know what they need. Hopefully it is possible to ask them for more guidance.